# Ruby: How to sort a json response using array or hashmap

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am getting my json response and parsing it, I am able to get the following models and identifiers respectively (see below). 
Now, I need to sort them only by the model, case-insensitive. So if I create an array it becomes difficult, if not impossible, to sort only by model and if I do hash I will not be able to create duplicated keys (model).
So what would be the best approach to sort this json response? thanks !!

```
 this is the model: 1 Series
  this is the identifier: Convertible
  this is the model: 1 Series
  this is the identifier: Coupe
  this is the model: 1 Series M
  this is the identifier: Coupe
  this is the model: 3 Series
  this is the identifier: Convertible
  this is the model: 3 Series
  this is the identifier: Coupe
  this is the model: 3 Series
  this is the identifier: Diesel
  this is the model: 3 Series
  this is the identifier: Sedan
  this is the model: 3 Series
  this is the identifier: Wagon
  this is the model: ALPINA B7
  this is the identifier: Sedan
  this is the model: ActiveHybrid 5
  this is the identifier: Sedan
  this is the model: ActiveHybrid 7
  this is the identifier: Sedan
  this is the model: ActiveHybrid X6
  this is the identifier: SUV
```

Comment: But what did you try? Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an array of objects whose class mixes in [Comparable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html).  You only have to implement `<=>` (aka. "the spaceship") and you could then call `sort` on your array.

Comment: How can I sort [["1 Series","Convertible"],["3 Series","Coupe"]] only using the "1 Series", "3 Series" ... case-insensitive? any help is really appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why array is impossible to sort? 
This will work.

```
[["1 Series","Convertible"],["3 Series","Coupe"]].sort
```

Comment: What would be the syntax to create this array using a loop? Thank you!!

Comment: And how would you sort only using the "1 Series", "3 Series" ... Thanks!! It has been a few days that I am working on it, so any help on getting this nailed is really appreciated. Thanks again!!

Comment: great!! I got it work by doing: nested = [["B","D"],["B","C"],["A","E"]].sort! do |sub1,sub2|
  result = sub1.join('').downcase <=> sub2.join('').downcase
  result
end

nested.each {|e| puts "'#{e}'"}